# Rails why isn't my api json format not showing up in the params hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am practicing with apis in RoR. The user clicks on a link on the root page and it does a Get call to the api and saves all the fields that I want to the db. But when I look at the params hash it is empty? Why is that and how would I go about adding to the params hash the JSON data?

controller

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController


  def index
  end

  def save_your_campaigns
    campaigns = Campaign.get_your_campaigns
    campaigns_attributes = JSON::parse(campaigns)
    campaigns_attributes.each {|attribute| Campaign.create(campaign_id: attribute["id"], name: attribute["name"], dpi: attribute["dpi"], length: attribute["length"] )}
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

model

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  def self.get_your_campaigns
    uri = URI.parse("https://example.site/api/v2/users")
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    request.content_type = "application/json"
    request.basic_auth("example@email.com", "238urfs393kmdsb2189aead01")
    req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
    }
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end
    return response.body
  end
end
```

view

```
<h1>Welcome!<h1>


 <%= link_to 'Get All Campaigns', save_campaigns_path %>
```

JSON data

```
[
  {
    "id" => 2758, 
    "dip" => "2.0", 
    "length" => 10, 
    "name" => "Cereal", 
    "total_remaining" => 100, 
    "status" => 6, 
    "is_retarget" => false
  }, 
  {
    "id" => 278563, 
    "dip" => "1.25", 
    "length" => 2, 
    "name" => "Pizza", 
    "total_remaining" => 123, 
    "status" => 6, 
    "supplier_link" => "http://www.developingmedia.com/adhoc.php?id=", 
    "incidence" => 50, , 
    "days_in_field" => 5, 
    "max_daily_completes" => nil, 
    "is_retarget" => false
  }, 
  { 
    "id" => 278564, 
    "dip" => "4.25", 
    "length" => 25, 
    "name" => "California", 
    "days_in_field" => 5,
  }
]
```

Comment: i guess this is typo mistake:  `Campaign.get_campaigns` should be `Campaign.get_your_campaigns`, right ?

Comment: @LamPhan yes it is a typo. But that is not the reason why the JSON data is not in params

Comment: what params do you concern about ? params on index page ?

Comment: @LamPhan yeah when they click the link to get their campaigns shouldn't the api json data be in the params?